# How would I go about applying physics to the player with bullet?

Tags: c++, opengl-3, bulletphysics

I've been trying to apply physics to the player controlled character and have come up with nothing. I've followed the demo and have created a character controller. From here though updating my camera's position and the controller's doesn't seem to work usually ending with a black screen.

So my question is how would go about updating both's position properly so it works as you think it would(game scenario).

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the [tutorials](http://bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Tutorial_Articles) step by step.

I think the solution to the problem that you are having right now lies [here](http://bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/MotionStates). (Synchronizing physics world and visual world).

Also, regarding the camera problem, some more information from your side might be productive.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are doing. Your question is rather vague.

For most FPSs bullets are done through tracing since they move far too fast for the regular update loop to be able to see any collision.

This post might help you quite a bit.

http://schabby.de/picking-opengl-ray-tracing/